# Marmalade corrupts textures when deployed to Android

Tags: marmalade

I'm currently writing an application for Android using Marmalade. I must say that I find the .mkb syntax highly annoying, regardless of that, Marmalade seems to be corrupting my textures, but only when I add the files to my .mkb file.

With the following MKB file, my output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKw0F.jpg)

```
#!/usr/bin/env mkb

files
{
    [Source]
    (Source)
    MobileMario.cpp
    Game.h
    Game.cpp
    Renderer.h
    Renderer.cpp
    Scene.h
    Scene.cpp
    Scene_Menu.h
    Scene_Menu.cpp
    Scene_Level.h
    Scene_Level.cpp
    GUI.h
    GUI.cpp
}

subprojects
{
    iwutil
    iw2dscenegraphcore
    iw2dscenegraph
    iwgx
    iwresmanager
    iwtween
}



assets {
    (data)
    mario.tga
    mario.gxfont

    (data/Textures)
    mario.png
    mario_logo.png
    options_background.png

    (data/Tilemaps)
    1_1_test.png
}

deployment
{
}
```

When I leave out the "assets" section of my .mkb file, the output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMiyY.png). The output it SHOULD have, is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVkBS.png), as you can see, the  fonts don't render on mobile, which probably means I need to add the files to my .mkb file, but doing so (or even adding one file), it corrupts everything.

Comment: What if you just put in the folder names without the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way Marmalade's "assets" section looks and everything seems to be working. Still don't know why it corrupted before, at least I don't have the problem anymore.